# RewriteBase not applying to current website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting

I have a website which is working until i have uploaded .htaccess file.
My directory path be like

```
/MY_PROJECT
```

And in `.htaccess` Starting code is

```
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

i also tried by putting

```
RewriteBase /MY_PROJECT
```

but still it shows an **Internal Server Error**

Comment: So you need to take a look into your http servers error log file to read what the actual issue is.

Comment: mine error_log is empty

Comment: I doubt that, actually. That log file is _never_ empty once you started the http server. Apart from that you actually received an error. So that will be logged. Could it be that you are referring to another file?